# Can't install anaconda3 because of the input output error

Tags: python, linux, input, output, anaconda

I want to install anaconda 3 ,however, I got this message.
How can I solve it?
plus. is there any binary code for anaconda3?

installing: python-3.6.3-hc9025b9_1 ...
tar: lib/python3.6/distutils/log.py: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Answer (score -1):

Your downloaded tar may be corrupted. Just try downloading again